# Dynamic content in google maps api v3 info windows on multiple custom markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the below js that implements a google map with a looped through set of custom markers. I need each marker to have a different infowindow so when you click the marker you get the content that is relevant. At the minute it doesn't open the infowindow and doesn't give me an error in console

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for(var i=0; i<google_map_item.length; i++)
    {
        latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(google_map_item[i].lat, google_map_item[i].lon)
        bounds.extend(latlon);
        var iconcolor = google_map_item[i].iconColor;
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlon,
            icon: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld=" + (i + 1) + "|"+iconcolor+"|000000",
            type: 'flat',
            icon_color: '#ff0000', 
            label_color: '#ffffff', 
            width: '20', 
            height: '20', 
            label_size: '11',
                            clickable: true
        });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        //marker.info.open(map, this);
                        infowindow.setContent(this.latlon);
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });


        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps - Multiple markers - 1 InfoWindow problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402667/google-maps-multiple-markers-1-infowindow-problem)

Answer (score 5):

```
var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,                                                        
          icon: 'miniMarker.png',
          info: destArr[i][9],
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(destArr[i][7], destArr[i][8])
});
var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'mouseover', function () {
        infowindow3.setContent(this.info);                              
        infowindow3.open(map, this);                        
});
```

Working example with more then 20 markers and info window

Answer (score 0):

The reference in the marker array was incorrect as outlined in this similar question

[Google Maps - Multiple markers - 1 InfoWindow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402667/google-maps-multiple-markers-1-infowindow-problem?rq=1)

Comment: I was facing also same problem in one info window, but after that i used an array for that and different marker with different infowindows. My problem is  solved you can test it for your also hope it will work.