# Info bubble always shows up on the last marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps - Multiple markers - 1 InfoWindow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402667/google-maps-multiple-markers-1-infowindow-problem)

I'm making a [map](http://mapa.site11.com/map.html) where I plot some towns and places.
As you will see, when you click on a marker, you are redirected to the corresponding page. But now I would like to put the link and some other information in an info bubble popover. So, I've edit my code to this:

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: beach[4], position: myLatLng});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng, map: map, title: beach[0], zIndex: beach[3], clickable: true, icon: beach[5],});
    marker[i] = marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() { 
      infobulle.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
}
```

But as you can [see here](http://mapa.site11.com/map2.html) the info bubble stays "blocked" on the last location. I really don't know how to sort this.

I have the same result with this :

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var beach = locations[i];
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
  var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: beach[4]});
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng, map: map, title: beach[0], zIndex: beach[3], clickable: true, icon: beach[5]});

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    infobulle.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

Last version :

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    processBeach(locations[i]);
  }
}
function processBeach(beach) {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
  var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: beach[4]});
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng, map: map, title: beach[0], zIndex: beach[3], clickable: true, icon: beach[5]});
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
infobulle.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my [jSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/MKSnD/2/show/). The code you are missing is

1. On Click you need to fetch the current infoWindow from the map and then update it with new information
2. If you want to keep windows open and close when people want to close then you have to set a toggle kind of variable so each window will be created on click and then when someone click on close it will go away. But i think you only need to complete first part.

The code you should look in my fiddle is from line 120 to 150 which does check for infowindow if it exists and then do open the same window on new marker so it moves from old marker and go to new. if you keep creating new windows the old ones will not close magically.

```
var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
      infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}}); // Get current info window
    if (infowindow){ // if infoWindow is there then use it else create new
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      infowindow.setContent(context.data.ht);
      jQuery("#customPopup").html(context.data.ht);
        jQuery("#customPopup").show(500);
    } else {
      $(this).gmap3({
        infowindow:{
          anchor:marker, 
          options:{content: context.data.ht}

        }
      });
        jQuery("#customPopup").html(context.data.ht);
        jQuery("#customPopup").show(500);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `marker` variable for two different purposes it seems.  One is as a single marker, and one as an array of markers.  But you don't need an array of markers, if you use closures.  Try this:

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    (function(beach) {
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
      var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: beach[4], position: myLatLng});
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng, map: map, title: beach[0], zIndex: beach[3], clickable: true, icon: beach[5]}))
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
        infobulle.open(map, marker);
      });
    }(locations[i]));
  }
}
```

By the way you also had a spurious comma at the end of the options array for `google.maps.Marker` which will cause problems in some browsers.

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use closures, this is equivalent:

```
function processBeach(beach) {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
  var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: beach[4], position: myLatLng});
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng, map: map, title: beach[0], zIndex: beach[3], clickable: true, icon: beach[5]}))
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    infobulle.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    processBeach(locations[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hum, I don't really understand what you have done with the beach function.

Comment: Yeah closures take a bit to get your head around.  What I am doing is defining and calling a function all in one go.  So I am defining an anonymous function, which takes a parameter named `beach` and then calling it, passing the value of `locations[i]` as the argument.  So inside the closure, `beach` has the value passed in from `locations[i]`, for the current iteration's value of `i`.  There is no problem with the value leaking, as happened in your code, because `beach` only exists inside the closure, and importantly is a _different variable_ for every iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: I just updated the answer to include a version without closures.

Comment: I understand! I have try with your code (I have edited it a bit, I put it in the post). The map is ok but there is no marker anymore...

Comment: Oh whoops, there is a copy-paste error.  I was creating the `Marker` object but not assigning it to anything.  Answer updated.

Comment: Yes I saw, there is a ; missing too and one uneeded ) but it's nothing