# Changing data in the info window with Google Map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) to create a custom Google Map. I've included a few other elements such as linking it up to Wordpress and clustering the markers.

It's all working great apart from the info in the info windows on each marker. I just can't seem to change the info within each one. I thought by changing the following lines it would change it but nothing affects it:

```
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
```

[This is the working map](http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/poh/)

Where can I put in my own custom data into the window? Also, if I could style the window on that would be even better.

---

It seems the clusterer is the problem, mainly this section, how can I take the html content and place it into the info window?

```
function load() {
  var cluster = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.375599, -3.471680),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var min = .999999;
  var max = 1.000002;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/phpsqlajax_genxml.php ", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

      var offsetLat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      var offsetLng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(offsetLat, offsetLng);
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        // infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                        // infowindow.open(map, marker, html);
                        infowindow.setContent(html); infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
      cluster.push(marker);
    }
    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster);
  });
}
```

Specifically this, it's not putting the html content through the clusterer... at least this is actually changing the data in the window, just need to output the html content without breaking the clusterer:

```
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                        infowindow.open(map, marker, html);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
      cluster.push(marker);
```

---

The closest I have it so far is this but it shows the same info for every marker. It's showing the html content:

```
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        // infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                        // infowindow.open(map, marker, html);
                        infowindow.setContent(html); infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
      cluster.push(marker);
```

Comment: Can you give your code with html use in it ?

Comment: @Ankit Just added an update, think I've found where the error is, just need to come up with a fix! You can view source to see the full code on the link provided, it's a bit much to paste here.

Comment: For a start do we need to create infowindow object ? or You omitted it. var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html}). And in addListener, infowindow.open(map, marker); Remove infowindow.setContent from addListener [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)

Comment: Another [link](http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/) or [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402667/google-maps-multiple-markers-1-infowindow-problem)

Comment: @Ankit I'm struggling with this. I can't quite work out what to move/adjust, would it be possible for a code example that uses my setup?

Comment: @Ankit The infowindow is set further up and I tried to remove the setContent part but that stopped the info window appearing at all.

Comment: Please try links I have provided. specially the one with link2

Comment: @Ankit The thing that is throwing me is the markers[i], it just won't show the content. I've had a look at the links but mine seems very different to what they have.

Comment: replace your infowindow code in addListener with 
infowindow.setContent(html);                       infowindow.open(map, marker);

Comment: @Ankit Very close! It's showing the html content but it's showing the same info for every pin. It relies on `markers[i]` to iterate through each one.

Comment: replace infowindow.open(map, marker); with infowindow.open(map, this);
and pass html in function(). So, it should look like function(marker, i,html)

Comment: @Ankit It's still showing the same info in all the infowindows. This is the working link - http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/poh/

Comment: Rob, I am watching http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/poh/ . I can see infowindow with different text on each marker ! one is Leeworks, Charity. another is Testy, Academic, another is Contact innovation, Business another is Toms Spaghetti Warehouse,
Clinical.     Isn't that what you want ?

Comment: @Ankit I literally just solved it (see answer below), thanks for the help, made me rethink it all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can't believe I didn't think of this sooner!!

It just a case of building the string in the listener.

```
  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/phpsqlajax_genxml.php ", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

      var offsetLat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      var offsetLng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(offsetLat, offsetLng);
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                        infowindow.setContent(html);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker, html);
                        // infowindow.setContent(html);
                        // infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
      cluster.push(marker);
    }
```

Comment: It works fine. Building the html string in the listener did the job.

Comment: I've just done this now too and yep works a charm. Also performance is WAY better than doing it in the main constructor of the infowindow outside the listener. Huge performance gain on my maps!!!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading it correctly. You are trying to set content 'after' setting the marker.

This should be the other way around. Move the piece where you set the html to before you push it to the cluster.

---

edit:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
  var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
  var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

  var offsetLat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  var offsetLng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng") * (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(offsetLat, offsetLng);
  //var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address});

  var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icon.icon,
    shadow: icon.shadow
  });
  //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  //              return function() {
  //                  infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
  //                  infowindow.open(map, marker, html);
  //              }
  //          })(marker, i));
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',  function(marker, i){infowindow.open(map,marker);})(marker, i);

  cluster.push(marker);
}
```

Not sure about the (marker, i) pieces. I assume they are used by the marker manager to keep trakc of what's what. Those two changes (I commented out your lines and added one below) seem to be the next logical step.

Comment: It's very close to working, I've just tried Ankit's comment (above) but it's showing the same info for every marker... it is picking up the html content though.

Comment: It didn't seem to make a difference changing the order.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Just tried the edited answer, it only seems to plot one marker with no infowindow. It seems `markers[i]` is essential. I've updated my question with the closest I've got.

Comment: It seems you are trying (and managing) to use the infowindow object without actually defining it.

Have you tried just throwing a definition in so it knows what an infowindow is?

Comment: Infowindow is defined further up. I've added the full code to my question (the second code box).

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar problem, i figure this out, to change the content in marker infowindow

```
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        id: "costume_ID",/*<---this is the start of the trick*/
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        icon: "../images/icon-bla.png",
        map: map,
        title: 'bla',
        labelContent: 'bla,bla,
        labelClass: "labels", 
        labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0}
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function() {
        return function(){
        infowindow.setContent(infor(this.id));/*<--- here is the trick*/
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    }});
```

and than set the function that will output whatever you whant, if you have the info in variables.

```
    function infor(im){
        return "<div><b>INFOWINDOW</b><br>Date: "+var[im].date+"<br>Sync:  "+var[im].sync+"...bla,bla,bla</div>";
    }/*THIS FUNCTION RETURN THE STING TO SHOW ION THE INFOWINDOW*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your closure. The `for` loop isn't handling your scope correctly. Extract all the code from inside the `for` loop into a separate function and the closure should work.