# Google Maps with cluster of markers and their info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a cluster of Google map marker’s. I am showing Google maps in a ModalPopupExtender on a button click. After map is loaded with marker’s I want to pop up info window on mouse over of marker’s. how can I keep the details of info window of each marker when map is loading with marker’s?.

```
  $('#map-canvas').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            for (var i = 0; i < asGridselectedRows.length; i++) {
                var row = asGridselectedRows[i];
                var Latitude = asGridMasterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "Latitude");
                var Longitude = asGridMasterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "Longitude");
                var messno = asGridMasterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "MessNo");
                var messnumber = messno.innerHTML.substring(6, messno.innerHTML.length - 7);
                var Lat = Latitude.innerHTML.substring(6, Latitude.innerHTML.length - 7);
                var Long = Longitude.innerHTML.substring(6, Longitude.innerHTML.length - 7);
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Long);
                map.setCenter(myLatLng);
                map.setZoom(13);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map
                });
                if (messnumber == '00')
                {
                    marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');
                }
                else
                {                   
                marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
                }
                marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the info window as part of the event listener.  See the example given in the answer here: [Changing data in the info window with Google Map markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114963/changing-data-in-the-info-window-with-google-map-markers?rq=1)

You can add attributes to each marker so that these can be referenced in the hover event.  In your case it looks like you could simply use the messno as an attribute and then reference your data table with the marker info in

Comment: To set an attribute for the marker, simply use marker.attrribute1 = 'my attribute value'

Comment: The example I shared then shows you how to call the infowindow on click, you can change the event from click to mouseover